# What is the second form of "read"?

Tags: tense, verbs, pronunciation

Recently my teacher told me that the second form of the word **read** (verb) is ***read***, but I have some doubts. Can someone from you please tell me the second form of "read" and how is it pronounced?

Comment: Any dictionary will show you the spelling and pronunciation of words.  Why would you have doubts?  If your teacher and your dictionary tell you the same thing why do you think they are lying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing that the "second form" probably means the simple past, then yes, the second form of *read* is indeed *read*, but it is pronounced differently.

> Present: I read /rid/

> Past:  I read /rɛd/

> Perfect: I have read /rɛd/

Comment: Note that _lead_ has the same alternation in the pronunciation, but unlike _read_, the spelling changes: _I lead_, _I led_, _I have led_. The word _lead_ /lɛd/ also exists, but it is a noun referring to a metallc element, not any part of the veb _lead_.